# .thunderbird in my home takes up too much space

Tags: thunderbird, home-directory

My home directory is nearly completely occupied.

```
/dev/sda7        28G   24G  2.1G  93% /home
```

`disk analysis` shows the top largest directory is `.thunderbird`. As shown in the screenshot. Is there any other way to optimize it, or solution for it, so that I can have more space at /home?

[image]

Comment: It's all the downloaded messages in the cache. (Yes, it stores them offline even if you use IMAP) You can delete the cache to free up space. See this question: http://superuser.com/questions/493757/why-is-my-thunderbird-folder-so-big

Comment: If you have space in another partition/disk, you can move it there and symlink to that in the home directory. Otherwise you will have to find another way to archive the messages, or just "clean house." :( (Hate to lose data myself.)

Comment: After cleaning up as suggested, set up folders to store important messages and delete those you don't need to help prevent this happening again...

Answer (score 0):

You can clean your GMail account to make free space.

Also if you want "more space" for your `/home` partition install GParted to manage partitions. Provided there's unallocated space or it can be carved out from other partitions, it's possible to extend `/home`.

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```